# Set image url to NetworkImageView using Data binding gives FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, android-databinding, networkimageview

I am using Volley Library for fetching image from server and display it using NetworkImageView in RecyclerView. When I am using Android Data Binding for the same, I am getting below exception.

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri
```

While using pragmatical approach( calling setImageUrl from Adapter itself) its otherwise and I am able to display Images.

```
  @BindingAdapter("imgurl")
   public void setImageUrl(NetworkImageView view, String imageURL) {
    Context context = view.getContext();
    ImageLoader mImageLoader = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    try {
        ImageLoader.getImageListener(view, R.drawable.story_big_default, R.drawable.story_big_default);
        Log.d("STORYMODEL", "setImageUrl: "+imageURL.trim());
        view.setImageUrl(imageURL.trim(), mImageLoader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.story_big_default);
    }
}

   <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/story_small_default"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@{storymodel.imgurl}" />
```

Kindly help, what possibly I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

it can be caused by the `imageURL.trim()` the url may have black spaces use `replace(" ","%20")`

Comment: What possibly can be the difference? Anyway I tried using "replace" , result is the same.I think it is more related to data binding and not URL as it works perfectly while calling it from RecyclerView's adapter.

Comment: an url with blank spaces may produces URISyntaxException exception, what is the loged url ?

Comment: Image is available on server and when I hit the url in browser I am able to view it. Exception I am getting is FileNotFound which is strange in this case.

Comment: is the storage permission is given ?

Comment: Yes, storage permission is given. Like I said, the error I am getting is only when I integrate android data binding.

Comment: it's a problem with the uri not the url, the imageloader read the image from internal storage, try to upload an other picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148054/discussion-between-jovinz-and-oussema-aroua).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing BindingAdapter paramater. This was related to mapping between dataitem in Model and Imageview. https://mobikul.com/data-binding-part-ii-image-binding/

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/campaign_logo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"           
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_rectangle"
        android:padding="2dp"
        app:imageUrl="@{helper.brandLogo}" />
```

In your image view create a new attribute 'imageUrl' under namespace 'app'. And in your data binding helper class or pojo create a method as below and a String value 'brandLogo'. Initialise the value of this variable with the url of the image.

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
public static void getBrandLogo(View view, String imageUrl) {
    NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView) view;
    imageView.setImageUrl(imageUrl, imageLoader);
}
```

**If you have worked with Volley you must be having knowledge about using ImageLoader to load image from network or you can use Picasso or other libraries to load in the same method

Furthermore you can also add a placeholder, follow the same steps as above by creating a new attribute and editing the binding adapter annotation as

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl", "placeholder", requireAll = false/true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_80"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_80"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_user_placeholder"
                    app:srcProfilePhoto="@{profileData.profilePhoto}" // pass url
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/gray"
                     />
```

and finally below code use in java file

```
@BindingAdapter("app:srcProfilePhoto")
    public static void srcProfilePhoto(ImageView view, String imageUrl) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
            RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_placeholder);
            Glide.with(view.getContext())
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .apply(options)
                    .into(view);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Use Picasso library for loading image in ImageView replace of  NetworkImageView

For example,

```
ImageView thumbNail;
```

For Loading Image in Imageview ,

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(url).noFade().into(thumbNail);
```